# How to implement these type of Edittext?

Tags: android-layout, android-edittext

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3QZoP.png)

They have little elevation effect and not outline box.

Answer (score 0):

Just create an xml file in your drawable folder name as **round_corner.xml**.And add this following code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@color/darkGray" />
            <corners android:radius="7dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item
        android:bottom="3dp"
        android:right="3dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@android:color/white" />
            <corners android:radius="7dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

At Last you add this xml in **background** property of your **Edittext** as follows:-

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/ed1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/round_corner"
  />
```